# SharePoint 2010 delegate controls with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to override the "SearchResultsPageUrl" property of the SmallSearchInputBox using a delegate via Visual Studio 2010. However nothing seems to be happening, below is the current setup I've got:

1. Created an empty SharePoint 2010 project
2. Added an "Empty Element" by via right-clicking on the project in solution explorer 
   selecting Add new item > Empty Element.
3. Named the "Empty Element" to "SearchBoxOverride"
4. In the "Elements.xml" file I added the follwing lines of code which now looks like the 
   below:

[image]

I then built the solution and deployed. Under "site collection features" I can see 
    that this has been activate, but the now the search box has disappeared. If I 
    deactivate the feature the search box reappears again.

The project looks like the below:

[image]

Have I missed a step which is causing for the search box to disappear?

Any assistance would be appreciated...

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The above works.... The problem I was having was that I was testing this on SharePoint 2010 Foundation this seems to be a limit of Foundation which I was not aware of until now. This works fine on all other versions of SharePoint 2010 (Standard, Enterprise)...